# Reversed Huffman coding

Tags: algorithm, math

Suppose I have a collection of words with a predefined binary prefix code. Given a very large random binary chunk of data, I can parse this chunk into words using the prefix code.

I want to determine, at least approximately (for random chunks of very large lengths) the expectation values of number of hits for each word (how many times it is mentioned in the decoded text).

At first glance, the problem appears trivial - the probability of each word being scanned from the random pool of bits is completely determined by its length (since each bit can be either 0 or 1). But I suspect this to be an incorrect answer to the problem above since words have different lengths and thus this probability is not the same as the expected number of hits (divided by the length of the data chunk).

UPD: I was asked (in comments below) to state this problem mathematically, so here it goes.

Let **w** be a list of words written with only zeros and ones (our alphabet consists of only two letters). Furthermore, no word in **w** is a prefix of any other word. Thus **w** forms a legitimate binary prefix code. I want to know (at least approximately) the mean value of hits, for each word in **w**, averaged over all possible binary chunks of data with fixed size **n**. **n** can be taken very large, much much larger than any of the lengths of our words. However, words have different lengths and this can not be neglected.

I would appreciate any references to attempts to solve this.

Comment: I can feel what you are asking is a good question, but still have problem understanding what you exactly mean. Could you state your problem in a more clear way (e.g. in mathematical language) or give some simple examples to illustrate?

Comment: @WhatsUp I added an update to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if you came up with the same solution as I. The expected value of occurences of a word with length `l` is `(1/2 ^ l) * (n - l + 1)`. Can you agree on this?

Comment: Do you have word-boundaries? (the first part of the kwesstion suggests you do, the second part suggests that you assume a bitstream as input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My brief answer: the expected number of hits (or rather the expected proportion of hits) can be calculated for every given list of words.

I will not describe the full algorithm, but just do the following example in detail for illustration: let us fix the following very simple list of three words: `0`, `10`, `11`.

For every `n`, there are `2^n` different data chunks of length `n` (I mean `n` bits), each occur with the same probability `2^(-n)`.

The first observation is that, not all the data chunks can be decoded exactly - e.g. the data `0101`, when you decode, there will remain a single `1` in the end.

Let us write `U(n)` for the number of length `n` data chunks that CAN be decoded exactly, and write `V(n)` for the others (i.e. those with an extra `1` in the end). The following recurrence relations are clear:

1. `U(n) + V(n) = 2^n`
2. `V(n) = U(n - 1)`

with the initial values `U(0)` = 1 and `V(0) = 0`.

A simple calculation then yields:

`U(n) = (2^(n + 1) + (- 1)^n) / 3`.

Now let `A(n)` (resp. `B(n)`, `C(n)`) be the sum of the number of hits on the word `0` (resp. `10`, `11`) for all the `U(n)` exact data chunks, and let `a(n)` (resp. `b(n)`, `c(n)`) be the same sum for all the `V(n)` inexact data chunks (the last `1` does not count in this case).

Then we have the following relations:

1. `a(n) = A(n - 1)`, `b(n) = B(n - 1)`, `c(n) = C(n - 1)`
2. `A(n) = A(n - 1) + U(n - 1) + A(n - 2) + A(n - 2)`
3. `B(n) = B(n - 1) + B(n - 2) + U(n - 2) + B(n - 2)`
4. `C(n) = C(n - 1) + C(n - 2) + C(n - 2) + U(n - 2)`

Explanation for the relations 2 3 4:

If `D` is an exact data chunk of length `n`, then there are three possibilities:

- `D` ends with `0`, and deleting this `0` yields an exact data chunk of length `n - 1`;
- `D` ends with `10`, and deleting this `10` yields an exact data chunk of length `n - 2`;
- `D` ends with `11`, and deleting this `11` yields an exact data chunk of length `n - 2`.

Thus, for example, when we sum up all the hit numbers for `0` in all exact data chunks of length `n`, the contributions of the three cases are respectively `A(n - 1) + U(n - 1)`, `A(n - 2)`, `A(n - 2)`. Similarly for the other two equalities.

Now, solving these recurrence relations, we get:

- `A(n) = 2/9 * n * 2^n + (smaller terms)`
- `B(n) = C(n) = 1/9 * n * 2^n + (smaller terms)`

Since `U(n) = 2/3 * 2^n + (smaller terms)`, our conclusion is that there are approximately `n/3` hits on `0`, `n/6` hits on `10`, `n/6` hits on `11`.

Note that the same proportions hold if we take also the `V(n)` inexact data chunks into account, because of the relations between `A(n)`, `B(n)`, `C(n)`, `U(n)` and `a(n)`, `b(n)`, `c(n)`, `V(n)`.

This method generalizes to any list of words. It's the same idea as if you were to solve this problem using dynamic programing - create status, find recurrence relation, and establish transition matrix.

### To go further

I think the following might also be true, which will simplify the answer further.

Let `w_1`, ..., `w_k` be the words in the list, and let `l_1`, ..., `l_k` be their lengths.

For every `i = 1, ..., k`, let `a_i` be the proportion of hits of `w_i`, i.e. for length `n` data chunks the expected number of hits for `w_i` is `a_i * n + (smaller terms)`.

Then, my feeling (conjecture) is that `a_i * 2^(l_i)` is the same for all `i`, i.e. if one word is one bit longer than another, then its hit number is a half of that of the other.

This conjecture, if correct, is probably not very difficult to prove. But I'm too lazy to think now...

If this is true, then we can calculate those `a_i` very easily, because we have the identity:

`sum (a_i * l_i) = 1`.

Let me illustrate this with the above example.

We have `w_1 = 0`, `w_2 = 10`, `w_3 = 11`, hence `l_1 = 1`, `l_2 = l_3 = 2`.

According to the conjecture, we should have `a_1 = 2 * a_2 = 2 * a_3`. Thus `a_2 = a_3 = x` and `a_1 = 2x`. The above equality becomes:

`2x * 1 + x * 2 + x * 2 = 1`

Hence `x = 1 / 6`, and we have `a_1 = 1 / 3`, `a_2 = a_3 = 1 / 6`, as can be verified by the above calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a simple machine that can recognize words: a DFA with an accepting state for each word.  To construct this DFA, start with a binary tree with each left-child-edge labeled 0 and each right-child-edge labeled 1.  Each leaf is either a word-accepter (if the path to that leaf down the tree is the word's spelling) or is garbage (a string of letters that isn't a prefix for any valid word).  We wire up "restart" edges from the leaves back to the root of the tree*.

Let's find out what the frequency of matching each word would be, if we had a string of infinite length.  To do this, treat the graph of the DFA as a Markov state transition diagram, initialize the starting state to be at the root with probability 1 and all other states 0, and find the steady state distribution (by finding the dominant eigenvector of the transition diagram's corresponding matrix).

Our string is not of infinite length.  But since n is large, I expect "edge effects" to not matter so much.  We can approximate the matching **frequency** by word by taking the matching **rate** by word and multiplying by n.  If we want to be more precise, instead of taking the eigenvector we could just take the transition matrix to the **n**th power and multiply that with the starting distribution to get the resulting distribution after n letters.

*This isn't quite precise, because this Markov system would spend some nonzero amount of time at the root, when after recognizing a word or skipping garbage it should immediately go to the 0-child or 1-child depending.  So we don't actually wire up our "restart" edges to a root: from a word-accepting node we wire up two restart edges (one to the 0-child and one to the 1-child of the root); we replace garbage nodes that are left-children with an edge to the 0-child; and we replace garbage nodes that are right-children with an edge to the 1-child.  In fact, if we set our initial state to 0 with probability 0.5 and 1 with probability 0.5, we don't even need the root.

EDIT: To use @WhatsUp's example, we start with a DFA that looks like this:

[image: DFA for WhatsUp example set of words]

We rewire it a little bit to restart after a word is accepted and get rid of the root node:

[image]

The corresponding Markov transition matrix is:

```
0.5    0  0.5  0.5
0.5    0  0.5  0.5
  0  0.5    0    0
  0  0.5    0    0
```

whose first eigenvector is:

```
0.333
0.333
0.167
0.167
```

Which is to say that it spends 1/3 of its time in the 0 node, 1/3 in 1, 1/6 in 10, and 1/6 in 11.  This is in agreement with @WhatsUp's results for that example.